# How to save in multiple table in cakephp by using getLastInsertId

Tags: cakephp-1.3

There are two table Contents and contentpreviews. I want to add the data in both table from a action. More that Contents table's last_insert_id will be save into contentpreviews table. How can handle it?

> ```
> $this->data['Content']['user_id']     = $uid;
> $this->data['Content']['content_category_id'] = $catname;
> $this->data['Content']['title']         = $contname;
> $this->data['Content']['description']           = $contdesc;
> $this->Content->create();                             
> $this->Content->save($this->data['Content']);
> /*****************CONTENT SAVE END*****************/
>
> if(!empty($arxml[$arrFirstNode]['Webpreview'])){
> $webPreViewItem = count(array_values($arxml[$arrFirstNode ['Webpreview']));                       
> $webPrevfileName  = array_values($arxml[$arrFirstNode]['Webpreview']);
>
> for($wpi=0; $wpi<$webPreViewItem; $wpi++){
>    $this->data['contentpreviews']['content_id']   = $this->Content->getLastInsertId();
>    $this->data['contentpreviews']['name']     = $webPrevfileName[$wpi];
>    $this->data['contentpreviews']['is_wap']      = 1;
> //$this->Contentpreview->create();
> ```
>
> //$this->Contentpreview->saveAll($this->data['Contentpreview']);
>       }
>    Now how can save data into contents and contentpreviews table all togethere?

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP allows you to save multiple model associations at once. [This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) will help you.

First you have to make an associated array, like given in the reference link. Then you should have to use the following code to save the data into contents and contentprviews table.

```
$this->Content->saveAssociated($this->requst->$data, array('deep' => true));
```

You can also use saveAll() method to save data into your multiple related tables in a single shot query.